# Что указать в spf для почты

Tags: email, dns, vds, ispmanager, spf

У меня есть один vds с ispmanager. 
На него припарковано три домена.
example.com
example1.com
example2.com

В настройках системы в isp указан первый домен example.com и с ним все норм, dkim, spf, все работает как надо.

Письма с остальных двух попадают в спам, исходники писем говорят, что письма идут с первого домена.

Я так понимаю проблема с spf, так как dkim работает.

У всех доменов автоматом пишется
v=spf1 ip4:255.255.255.255 a mx ~all

Я смотрел документацию не знаю какого года и там были варианты для почтового сервера. 
Я пробовал: a:example.com -all и a:mail.example.com
Но безрезультатно.

Подскажите как настроить почту на одном VDS со множеством доменов чтобы письма не попадали в спам.

Comment: У меня так: `v=spf1 mx a:example1.com a:example2.com -all`

Comment: @defrag а где эта запись указана? на основном домене?

Comment: Не скажу за ispmanager (видел его последний раз лет 15 назад), но смысл тут такой: на DNS сервере, который "держит" записи всех ваших доменов, а точнее их почтовиков (на хостингах, это как правило один и тот же DNS сервер), надо прописать spf. Более правильно в вашем случае будет скорее так: `v=spf1 mx a:mail.example1.com a:mail.example2.com -all`если MX-ы доменов имеют имена mail. Попробуйте.

Comment: @defrag спасибо, вечером попробую, отпишусь

Comment: @defrag попробовал, но наверно не так пробую, ничего не выходит. Я прописал эту запись на первый домен `example.com` прямо в панели хостера и в isp тоже. Пробовал разные варианты, но никак. Я 100% что-то не так делаю.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь этой штукой https://mxtoolbox.com/ очень полезная, чтобы проверять свои настройки + я бы обратился в техподдержку хостера. Возможно все настраивается очень просто.

Comment: @defrag спасибо, пока что ничего не получается, будем разбираться...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос задан давно, но думаю тема актуальная всегда. Конечно, настройка почты на виртуальных серверах часто непредсказуемая и та ещё заноза. Здесь главное уделить внимание и значение всем атрибутам, знать их предназначение, как шпаргалка [статья](https://hyperhost.ua/info/ru/sozdanie-i-nastroyka-spf-zapisi-na-hostinge-v-panelyah-ispmanager-i-cpanel). А так в SPF записи Вам нужно указать все ІР адреса, что будут доверенными отправителями для вашего домена. Это можно сделать несколькими способами.

Первый:

```
v=spf1 ip4:IP-1 ip4:IP-2 ip4:IP-3 a mx ~all
```

где `IP-1` — основной ІР сервера (так как отправка с PHP-скриптов происходит с основного ІР сервера), а остальные ІР-адреса, на котором(ых) расположен(ы) домен(ы) и их почтовые домены что указаны в МХ-записях.

Второй — по аналогии, как вам порекомендовали ранее:

```
v=spf1 ip4:IP-1 mx a:example1.com a:example2.com ~all
```

где также указан основной ІР сервера, и далее считываются `А` записи, куда направлены Ваши домены.